# Snowfall Animations Using JavaScript & CSS - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, methods

**The Plan**

I want to make a animation using JavaScript and CSS, The plan is to make snow fall from the top of the div to the bottom. In short currently I create a div and just append a few child DOM elements that will be created with JavaScript and appended to the already created parent. The snow will also pick up when the browser window changes and then automatically create. The code is done using OOP and it currently will change the CSS properties of each new child DOM element that was created to increase the top and left properties (they will all be set to position absolute) and once the DOM element is off screen it will reset and start over only making sure to stick to use the limit I set in the Object property.

---

**Problem**

Currently If I run this method `snow.animate` in a `setInterval` - it says that it cant find the length property of the array that I pushed all the created child DOM elements in, but if i `console.log()` the array and try and get the `length` of the array then it actually shows me the `length`. I logged before the `for` loop and inside it to check if I can get the length of the array and it gets it but not when run through the `setInterval`.

---

**Question**

My question is, am I missing something or will I need to just make separate `function` and not use a `Object` to store all the `methods`?

**note** - I made a while loop inside the animation `method` - I felt very uncomfortable doing this. Is this safe or bad practice and is there another way of using the `while loop` to create the child elements that will be pushed in the array to use in the for loop that comes after.

---

**DEMO Code - JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/sb9o0t4m/**

*HTML*

`<div id="snowglobe"></div>`

*CSS*

```
body {
  background-color: #000;
    margin: 0;
}
/*---------------Snow Flakes--------------*/

#snowglobe {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 650px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#snowglobe .flake {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
}
```

*JS*

```
var snow = {
    //variables
    width: window.innerWidth,height: 650,flakeCount: 10,
    gravity: 0.7,windSpeed: 20,flakes: [],
    currentFlake: 0,snowGlobe: document.getElementById('snowglobe'),
    //methods
    getRandom: function(min,max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    },
    animate: function(){
        //while loop
        while (this.currentFlake < this.flakeCount){
            var flake = document.createElement('div'),
            newFlake;
            flake.className = "flake";
            flake.style.fontSize = this.getRandom(20,50) + 'px';
            flake.style.top = this.getRandom(0,this.height) + 'px';
            flake.style.left = this.getRandom(0,this.left) + 'px';
            flake.innerHTML = "*";
            newFlake = this.snowGlobe.appendChild(flake);
            //set a speed property to the newflake obj
            newFlake.speed = this.getRandom(1,100);
            this.flakes.push(newFlake);
            this.currentFlake++;
        }
        var flakes = this.flakes;
        //use the array of dom elements
        for(var i = 0; i < flakes.length; i++){
            positionX = false;
            positionY = false;
            //new Y position
            positionY = parseFloat(flakes[i].style.top) + (flakes[i].speed / 100) * this.gravity;
            if(positionY > this.height){
                positionY = 0 - parseInt(flakes[i].style.fontSize);
                positionX = getRandom(0, width);
            }
            //new X position
            if (!positionX) positionX = parseFloat(flakes[i].style.left) + Math.sin(positionY / this.windSpeed);
            if (positionX < -20) positionX = this.width + 20;
            if (positionX > this.width + 20) positionX = -20;
            // Set new position
            flakes[i].style.top = positionX + 'px';
            flakes[i].style.left = positionX + 'px';
        }
    }
}
//check browser window, did it resize?
window.onresize = function(){
    snow.width = window.innerWidth;
    console.log(snow.width);
}
setInterval(snow.animate, 1000/60);
//if you want, coment out the above line and uncoment the one below to see the snow loading
//snow.animate();
```

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is not set to the proper object. For details, see [the "this" problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem).

You could call the method like this:

```
setTimeout( function(){ snow.animate(); }, 1000/60 );
```

but it's better to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```
var snow = {
    ...
    animate: function() {
        ...
        window.requestAnimationFrame( (function(){ this.animate() }).bind(this) );
    }
}
```

and you could simply start the animation by calling `snow.animate()`.

I also took the liberty of fixing some errors that you wouldn't be aware of because the code wouldn't run (referencing `width` without `this` etc..).
Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb9o0t4m/1/).

I left your initialisation loop as is; since it only runs once, normally you'd put this in a separate method, usually a constructor or initialisation method. The only downside here is that there is the overhead of checking the while condition on each animation frame.

Comment: I went over and saw what you meant. apologies for my noobness but thank you for the answer! ill have a look at the link you sent and the requests animation frame :)

Comment: Oh no problem at all! - you can't be sure a JavaScript works properly until you've been able to run it completely. I was just curious to see it work :-)